# Specify padding for creating digital signature on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, encryption, cryptography

In iOS there is method `SecKeyRawSign()` to generate signature , that let you specify padding type.

```
OSStatus SecKeyRawSign (
   SecKeyRef key,
   SecPadding padding,
   const uint8_t *dataToSign,
   size_t dataToSignLen,
   uint8_t *sig,
   size_t *sigLen
);
```

On OSX it won't work in that way, I'm using Security Transforms to do that as described here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/SigningandVerifying/SigningandVerifying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010801-CH4-SW3 .

```
  /* Create the transform objects */
    signer = SecSignTransformCreate(privatekey, &error);
    if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }


    SecTransformSetAttribute(
                             signer,
                             kSecTransformInputAttributeName,
                             sourceData,
                             &error);
    if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }

  signature = SecTransformExecute(signer, &error);
    if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }

    if (!signature) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Signature is NULL!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
```

1. Is there any way to set padding here? Please provide example if it's possible.
2. On iOS in Security Framework, there is define `kSecPaddingPKCS1SHA256` for **SHA256** to set padding. On OSX there isn't , so what should be equivalent to use? I need to set padding for SHA256.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, experimental code, but you need to specify the `PKCS1` padding, that you're using a `SHA-2` Digest type, and that the size is `256`:

```
SecTransformSetAttribute(
                     signer,
                     kSecPaddingKey,
                     kSecPaddingPKCS1Key,
                     &error);
if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }

SecTransformSetAttribute(
                     signer,
                     kSecDigestTypeAttribute,
                     kSecDigestSHA2,
                     &error);
if (error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }

int digestLength = 256;
CFNumberRef dLen = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &digestLength);
Boolean set = SecTransformSetAttribute(
                     signer,
                     kSecDigestLengthAttribute,
                     dLen,
                     &error);
CFRelease(dLen);
if (!set || error) { CFShow(error); exit(-1); }
```